# My ubuntu system is asking login again and again when i even entered the correct login details?

Tags: login, login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in Dell desktop. I am unable to login into my desktop.
when i enter my login details its just coming again to login page without entering into my dashboard? Please help me...

Comment: Does logging in as *guest* work? Does it work if you select a different session type, like *Ubuntu 2D*? Also, are you able to log in non-graphically in a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console)? To attempt this, press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and enter your username and password as prompted. As you enter your password, you won't see any placeholder characters (like `*`). That's OK, just type it in and press enter. If you're able to log in, please run `df -h` and report the output. (The best way to provide this information is to *edit your question*.)

Comment: Close voter(s): This might be a duplicate of *something*, but it is *not* a duplicate of any question about how to reset a password. Here, the problem is that login succeeds but the display manager fails to start a desktop (or starts one but it terminates immediately).

Comment: Please use the search on this site using `login screen loop` and you'll find some similar questions. Attempt proposed solutions from there and if it fails, include the steps and results here. With the currently provided information it's not answerable, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced the same problem in my Ubuntu 14.04. I tried every solution present on Internet. after getting frustrated I tried to do something similar to what I thought is appropriate. I deleted the .profile file and restart system, after that I was able to login to same user. Following are the steps :

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>  to go to TTYs.
- Type: `sudo mv .profile .profile.backup`
- Then Type: `sudo reboot`

Comment: `Ctrl+F2` for Ubuntu in VirtualBox brings the command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Well did you tried to double check on your display manager. That may be there is a clash between gdm & lightdm.

---

> Try <kbd>CLT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> login to your account and `sudo service lightdm start`